# Jenkins master server load test

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, load-testing, locust

I am running a jenkins master server.
About 30 agent nodes are registered in the jenkins master server, and there are a total of 1000 jobs.
So I want to load test not only the node but also the master server.
I would like to use a load testing tool like Jmeter or locust.
How should I proceed with load testing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you need to test exactly.

Well-behaved load test should replicate real life usage of the system with 100% accuracy. If you want to check how many maximum users will be able to use Jenkins system without any issues using their browsers - you need to [simulate real user using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) accessing Jenkins as it would be in reality.

1. Each user should have its own credentials
2. You need to simulate [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers), [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), [think times](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9), etc.
3. You need to define the workload, i.e. what different logical groups of users be doing, i.e. starting jobs, browsing, reading build results, etc.

With JMeter you can even record your test scenario(s) using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), with Locust you will need to [write each and every request definition in Python](https://github.com/locustio/locust#write-user-test-scenarios-in-plain-old-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use Jmeter distributed testing:
[Official documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Here are some important considerations:

1. Design of your test cases
2. Test data management
3. Define your load model & rate
4. Define metrics you'd like to measure